# Remove outliers (3*IQR) from each column separately

Tags: r, function

Hi I have a large dataframe with many columns. I want to replace outliers as "NA" based on value of each column+/- 3*IQR for all the columns in the dataset. I have tried something like this but everything goes FALSE. Would appreciate any advice. I get the following error message using the code below.
In match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

```
IsOutlier <- apply(brain_measures, function(x) {
  lowerq = quantile(brain_measures, na.rm = TRUE)[2]
  upperq = quantile(brain_measures, na.rm = TRUE)[4]
  iqr = upperq - lowerq 
  lower_threshold = lowerq-(iqr*3) 
  upper_threshold=upperq+(iqr*3)
  brain_measures < lower_threshold | brain_measures>upper_threshold
}
)
The dataset called brain_measures is very fairly large (150 columns) and I need to perform some QC on each individual column to replace the outliers as missing so that in they will not be included in the regression models of my analysis. The below dataset has made up values but the structure is this with many more columns!

id        cuneus       hippocamp    icv         amygdala putamen
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2        5
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2        4
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       10
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2        1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2        4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4        8
```

Comment: `lower_threshold` should be `lowerq - iqr * 3` and `upper_threshold` should be `upperq + iqr * 3`.

Comment: Suggestion: with larger amounts of data, `quantile` will get more expensive. Capture its return value and use *that* value twice, as in `quant <- quantile(data, na.rm = TRUE); lowerq <- quant[2]; upperq <- quant[4];`. (I agree with Darren's suggestion for the `*_threshold` values.)

Comment: Did you publish this anywhere? It looks pretty cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method to use IQR on each column.

I find it typically very useful to come up with a simple "verb" function that can be easily tested and demonstrated, and then applied as many times as needed.

```r
is_outlier <- function(x, iqrfac = 3) {
  quants <- quantile(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  iqr <- quants[4] - quants[2]
  !is.na(x) & (x < (quants[2] - iqrfac*iqr) | (quants[4] + iqrfac*iqr) < x)
}
```

Looking at your sample data above, I changed one value in `$hippocamp` to get just a little more outlierishness (in addition to the last value in `$amygdala`) ...

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
id        cuneus       hippocamp    icv         amygdala putamen
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2        5
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2        4
3          4.7        13.2          1.3         0.2       10
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2        1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2        4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4        8")

lapply(dat, is_outlier)
# $id
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $cuneus
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $hippocamp
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $icv
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $amygdala
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# $putamen
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

From there, we can use a combination of `lapply` to return a list of logical vectors (where `TRUE` means that value in that vector needs to be replaced), `replace` (to do the replacing), and `Map` (to map the `replace` function over each column and each vector of logicals). It might seem complicated, but ...

```r
dat[] <- Map(replace, dat, lapply(dat, is_outlier), NA)
dat
#   id cuneus hippocamp icv amygdala putamen
# 1  1    5.1       3.5 1.4      0.2       5
# 2  2    4.9       3.0 1.4      0.2       4
# 3  3    4.7        NA 1.3      0.2      10
# 4  4    4.6       3.1 1.5      0.2       1
# 5  5    5.0       3.6 1.4      0.2       4
# 6  6    5.4       3.9 1.7       NA       8
```

`Map` is effectively like `lapply`.

```r
lapply(mydat, myfunc)
# "unrolls" to
list(
  myfunc(mydat[[1]]),
  myfunc(mydat[[2]]),
  myfunc(mydat[[3]]),
  ...,
  myfunc(mydat[[n]])
)

# equivalently
Map(myfunc, mydat) # reversed arguments
# "unrolls" to
list(
  myfunc(mydat[[1]]),
  myfunc(mydat[[2]]),
  myfunc(mydat[[3]]),
  ...,
  myfunc(mydat[[n]])
)

# extended
Map(otherfunc, datA, datB, datC)
# "unrolls" to
list(
  otherfunc(datA[[1]], datB[[1]], datC[[1]]),
  otherfunc(datA[[2]], datB[[2]], datC[[2]]),
  otherfunc(datA[[3]], datB[[3]], datC[[3]]),
  ...,
  otherfunc(datA[[n]], datB[[n]], datC[[n]])
)
# assuming that datA, datB, and datC are all the same length
```

---

Darren's comment to use `lowerq` and `upperq` in place of `data` is spot-on. Allow me to show you *why* this is the case.

```r
set.seed(42)
data <- rnorm(20)
data
#  [1]  1.37095845 -0.56469817  0.36312841  0.63286260  0.40426832 -0.10612452  1.51152200
#  [8] -0.09465904  2.01842371 -0.06271410  1.30486965  2.28664539 -1.38886070 -0.27878877
# [15] -0.13332134  0.63595040 -0.28425292 -2.65645542 -2.44046693  1.32011335

quant <- quantile(data, na.rm = TRUE)
lowerq <- quant[2]
upperq <- quant[4]
iqr <- upperq - lowerq

cbind(data, lower=data-(iqr * 3), upper=data+(iqr * 3))
#              data     lower    upper
#  [1,]  1.37095845 -3.395548 6.137465
#  [2,] -0.56469817 -5.331204 4.201808
#  [3,]  0.36312841 -4.403378 5.129635
#  [4,]  0.63286260 -4.133644 5.399369
#  [5,]  0.40426832 -4.362238 5.170774
#  [6,] -0.10612452 -4.872631 4.660382
#  [7,]  1.51152200 -3.254984 6.278028
#  [8,] -0.09465904 -4.861165 4.671847
#  [9,]  2.01842371 -2.748082 6.784930
# [10,] -0.06271410 -4.829220 4.703792
# [11,]  1.30486965 -3.461636 6.071376
# [12,]  2.28664539 -2.479861 7.053152
# [13,] -1.38886070 -6.155367 3.377645
# [14,] -0.27878877 -5.045295 4.487717
# [15,] -0.13332134 -4.899827 4.633185
# [16,]  0.63595040 -4.130556 5.402457
# [17,] -0.28425292 -5.050759 4.482253
# [18,] -2.65645542 -7.422962 2.110051
# [19,] -2.44046693 -7.206973 2.326039
# [20,]  1.32011335 -3.446393 6.086619
```

Subtracting `iqr*3` from `data` is subtracting it from each value within `data`. That means that all of the `_threshold` values will always be `iqr*3` below and `iqr*3` above each `data`. This is equivalent to saying:

```r
data > (data - (iqr*3)) | data < (data - (iqr*3))
```

which is *always* true.

Instead,

```r
cbind(data, lower = lowerq-(iqr * 3), upper = upperq+(iqr * 3))
#              data     lower    upper
#  [1,]  1.37095845 -5.046661 6.075187
#  [2,] -0.56469817 -5.046661 6.075187
#  [3,]  0.36312841 -5.046661 6.075187
#  [4,]  0.63286260 -5.046661 6.075187
#  [5,]  0.40426832 -5.046661 6.075187
#  [6,] -0.10612452 -5.046661 6.075187
#  [7,]  1.51152200 -5.046661 6.075187
#  [8,] -0.09465904 -5.046661 6.075187
#  [9,]  2.01842371 -5.046661 6.075187
# [10,] -0.06271410 -5.046661 6.075187
# [11,]  1.30486965 -5.046661 6.075187
# [12,]  2.28664539 -5.046661 6.075187
# [13,] -1.38886070 -5.046661 6.075187
# [14,] -0.27878877 -5.046661 6.075187
# [15,] -0.13332134 -5.046661 6.075187
# [16,]  0.63595040 -5.046661 6.075187
# [17,] -0.28425292 -5.046661 6.075187
# [18,] -2.65645542 -5.046661 6.075187
# [19,] -2.44046693 -5.046661 6.075187
# [20,]  1.32011335 -5.046661 6.075187
```

(Which is still always true in this example, but at least you can see that the comparisons are done on single values for each of lower/upper.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! My code actually doesn't work and I can't find much about how to perform this function on each column separately!

Comment: I might be able to help, but *"doesn't work"* is not enough information, and your question is not fully reproducible. Are you saying that this code does not work at all for you?

Comment: no and I've tried to find other similar posts but it looks like they do it column by column. I've not used functions much in R...  I'll edit my question now with a format of the data and the error I'm getting! I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed solution and explanation. Out of curiosity, is there any advantages of using map compared to lapply as in this instance dat[] <- Map(replace, dat, lapply(dat, is_outlier), NA)" as you said they are practiclaly the same?

Comment: `Map` is "needed" there because it needs to apply the `replace` function on the first "element" (column) of `dat` and the first element (vector of a list) of the `lapply()` return; repeating with the second and the second; etc. Because it's two lists (one is a frame, a special kind of list), it needs something that can handle two or more data arguments. Ergo `Map`. There are workarounds. One would be to store `outs <- lapply(dat, is_outlier)`, then `lapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) replace(dat[[i]], outs[[i]], NA))`.